# jquery loop script through all cells in a column of a table

Tags: jquery, each

just an FYI i am terrible at jquery, very very bad.

Okay so onto the question, i have a table, and i want to format the numbers for every cell in the 5th column so far my script only works for the first cell in column 5 and then it duplicates the first cell over the rest of them whereas i want it to loop over each cell and provide a unique cell value.

What I'm doing with my script

1. I'm adding an ID onto every cell in the 5th column (i cant add one manually thus this is the only way i can do it)
2. I'm adding a £ and then formatting the numbers to 2 decimal places
3. Finally i need to rerun step 2 over all instanced of id 'test'

Im dealing with numbers such as this

- 46.244131455399064
- 48.82629107981221
- 0.9823076923076923

As you can see this just makes horrible reading, thus the reason i'm doing this script.

I've added my code to the bottom.

Thanks for any and all help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').prop('id', 'test');
    $('#test').each(function(){
        var test = parseFloat($('#test').text()).toFixed(2);
        $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').empty().append('£', test);
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use a class, not an ID for multiple elements.     Is it possible to simply class your table td as 'class=formatted' an use a selector on that classname instead of dom-marking and finding everything?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the message, agree it should be a class and not an ID the issue i have is that there's already a class and not an ID and i don't know how to append a class onto a class without wiping out the old class, its an API i am using so i need that class to be the same as im typing this it hit me i can make the class the same as it should be + the old one with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JQuery documentation the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) will select a single element.
Selecting several elements can easily be done by using class. You can add class like this:

```
$('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').addClass('formatted');
```

And then select elements by class:

```
$('.formatted').each(function(){
    var test = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
    $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').empty().append('£', test);
});
```

Also notice that selector inside `each` function is changed from `$('#test')` to `$(this)`. In the first case you would always select the first element with id=test whereas in the latter case you'll get the current element in the loop.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for this reply, ive updated the code and now im getting "£NaN" any ideas?

Thanks again.

Comment: I got it!

I changed  $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').empty().append('£', test); to  $(this).empty().append('£', test);

Thank you for all the help